# Intel HD Graphics Works on Unity, but no in Gnome shell

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, intel-graphics

I cant play starcraft 1 in Gnome shell(to slow), in unity runs perfect .Why?

Answer (score 1):

This could have to do with Compiz, it could also have to do with your graphics drivers, but I'm not sure which or if there's more that I'm missing.

Check compiz to make sure that the state is the same in both Unity and Gnome, and check to see which graphics drivers are in use.

I may be missing other variables at play here.

Edit: I just remembered that Starcraft doesn't run natively on *nix so you must be using wine -- check the wine settings for any differences when you run in Gnome compared to Unity.

Comment: ok, i'll check compiz

Comment: I remember im not using compiz, i installing but doesnt work

Comment: It just occurred to me now that Starcraft doesn't run natively on *nix, so you're likely using Wine or a derivative; check the settings in Wine? Perhaps by some freak chance the settings are different in Unity and Gnome? I'm grasping at straws now to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

mutter could grabbing 3d accelation from your card, and compiz doesn't , compiz has  had lots of work over the years to help speed up full screen 3d applications